# How to backup a complete file?

Tags: c#, backup

What is the most efficient way to make a backup of a file when it's being opened into the program, so that when the user changes and saves it, there is always a way to go back?

Example:

```
    private void open_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ofd.DefaultExt = "";
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            fileIn = ofd.FileName;
            fileOut = Path.GetTempFileName();
            string encoded = File.ReadAllText(fileIn);
    etc. etc. etc
}
```

The file that gets loaded into the program needs to get backed up as backup_01 and put in the same folder as the original file. When backup_01 exists, backup as backup_02, and so on).

Examples are more than welcome!

Comment: `File.Exists` and `File.Copy` usually work for me.

Comment: What kind of file? Roughly how large?

Comment: What did you try? your description of the solution sounds ok.

Comment: @Richard The file is less than one MB, and has no extension.

Answer (score 0):

I would generally create a copy of the file itself, place it in a "backup" folder, and apply some naming scheme to it to indicate its age.

Eg: `folder/originalFile.xyz` ==> `folder/backup/originalFile_2013-04-14-12-48.bak`

Update/afterthought: I think the efficiency of this will depend on the OS performing the Copy-operation, but it should in general not be too bad. Unless you have good reason to do so, I would avoid trying to add extra logic to do it more efficiently.

*Update in response to comment*:

I won't provide a detailed implementation here, but I'll try to point you in the right direction: Check out **[System.IO.File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx)**, specifically the methods `Copy` and `Exists`. ([This list of other common IO-taks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404278.aspx) may also be useful)

With these, you should be able to check if a file exists (eg. if you already have "`backup_1.xyz`" in your backup-folder), and based on that, generate a new name for your next backup file.

Create a loop that replaces `1` with increasing numbers until you find a "free" filename, and then copy the original file to a new file with that name.

Good luck! :)

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to do it with the backup_01, backup_02 etc? Placing it in a special backup folder is a good idea by the way.

Comment: Updated my answer - no code, but hopefully some useful pointers.